# PHPMailer 5.2.x - Centrally set PHPMailer SMTPAuth credentials

Tags: phpmailer, smtp-auth

We inherited an older PHP application. It is an online shop application coded in weird style. Each mail procedure has been coded into the responsive PHP file on the fly. There are lots of files which can hold code to send out mails.
Problem is, the new webserver uses a mailserver that demands SMTPAuth to accept mails for sending. The code doesn't provide any SMTPAuth credentials because the former hosting didn't use it.

The scripts are using PHPMailer.
My question is if there is any way to centrally set SMTPAuth credentials (host, username, password) which will be used by PHPMailer automatically always while sending out mails?

I do not want to touch the foreign code and alter each script so it uses SMTPAuth like:

```
$mail->IsSMTP = true;
$mail->Host = "blah";
$mail->Username = "xxx";
```

and so on.
I hope my intention is clear. Please ask if there are questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't edit the original files - otherwise when you update PHPMailer, your code will break - subclass instead, like this:

```
class myMailer extends PHPMailer {
    public function __construct($debug = false) {
        parent::__construct($debug);
        $this->Username = 'username';
        $this->Password = 'password';
        $this->isSMTP();
        $this->SMTPAuth = true;
    }
}
```

then use it whenever you want an instance, so instead of saying

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

say

```
$mail = new myMailer;
```

This approach is how you should always use libraries; it's not specific to PHPMailer.

Comment: Thank you, Synchro. Done so!
Now I have to edit each PHP template that sends mail. But it is much better your way.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

Just set the values in class.phpmailer.php of the public vars:

```
$Mailer // to "smtp"
$Host // to the mail host
$SMTPAuth // to true
$Username // to the mail accounts username
$Password // to the mail accounts password
```

That's all.

Comment: Don't do this; you should never need to edit the contents of libraries.